# what pattern to use when creating javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop

what is the best way to create classes ( as in OOP) in Javascript ?
Right now I am using the following pattern . Is it ok ?

```
var myclass = (function() {
var _name;
var baseObject = {
    a: 10,
    c: function() {
        return _name + " world " + privateFunc();
        }
};
function privateFunc() { return _name + "-ba"; };

function myclass(name) {
    _name = name;
    this.x = 9;
};
myclass.prototype = baseObject;
return myclass; })();
```

Comment: That looks quite similar to the way coffeescript compiled class output looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best" way.  There are a few OOP patterns in JavaScript, and the one you mentioned is one of them (and also a popular one). It is essentially a prototypical (or pseudo-classical) pattern with a closure to encapsulate private class-based static variables.

There are other patterns (e.g. the functional pattern recommended by Douglas Crockford).

I personally recommend the pseudo-classical pattern (although which pattern is best is a hot area of debate).

If you are doing OOP with JavaScript, I **strongly** recommend that you look into adopting a JavaScript library that has OOP built in, such as [The Dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) or the [Closure Library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/).  Other libraries (e.g. jQuery, MOOtools, Ext etc.) all have OOP modules and/or plugins.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on my current pattern. Currently I am adding codes to an existing software that use jQuery . I wonders if Dojo or Closure library works with jQuery ...

Comment: Dojo or Closure can both work with jQuery, but there is no need to because jQuery will duplicate much of their functions.  You're better off sticking with jQuery and its OOP plugin's.  I understand that John Resig is investigating into building a formal class system into jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, the best way to create classes in JavaScript is "don't". Forgive me for being blunt, but when working with JavaScript, try to forget about classes – they don't exists here – and accept that the language only deals with objects.

Not having classes in the language, means less code to be written. In typical applications, most objects don't have any siblings. You will only ever have one `document`, one `window`, one `userList`, etc. Create these objects by using object literal notation:

```
var userList = {
    users: []
};
```

While there are no classes in JavaScript, there are *constructors* and *prototypes*. These concepts come in handy when you have several objects that are similar (eg users contained in a `userlist`). Your code sample uses both of these concepts. Using names like `myclass`, it is hard to tell what you are trying to model. Here's an example of a `User` constructor and an extention to it's prototype:

```
var User = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

User.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return "Hello, my name is " + this.name;
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest you add "In my opinion" because the pros/cons of OOP with JavaScript is still hotly debated. A lot of people will disagree with you that "don't" do OOP is the best.

Comment: @Stephen: You are probably right. Added the IMHO-disclaimer up front :)

Comment: What I don't understand (coming from C++) is why there's so much bickery about whether JS has classes or not. Your answer, even though you claim otherwise is creating classes. Irrelevant of implementation details - logically your defining a particular kind of object, with the ability to have functions, properties and multiple instances (as well as inheritance).

Answer (score 7):

The following example illustrates a pattern that I personally developed over time.

It exploits scoping to allow private fields and methods.

```
Employee = (function(){

  // private static field
  var staticVar;

  // class function a.k.a. constructor
  function cls()
  {
    // private instance field
    var name = "";
    var self = this;

    // public instance field
    this.age = 10;

    // private instance method
    function increment()
    {
        // must use self instead of this
        self.age ++;
    }

    // public instance method  
    this.getName = function(){
        return cls.capitalize(name);
    };

    this.setName = function(name2){
        name = name2;
    };

    this.increment = function(){
        increment();
    };

    this.getAge = function(){
        return this.age;
    };
  }

  // public static field
  cls.staticVar = 0;

  // public static method
  cls.capitalize = function(name){
      return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
          name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  };

  // private static method
  function createWithName(name)
  {
    var obj = new cls();
    obj.setName(cls.capitalize(name));
    return obj;
  }

  return cls;
})();

john = new Employee();
john.setName("john");

mary = new Employee();
mary.setName("mary");
mary.increment();

alert("John's name: " + john.getName() + ", age==10: "+john.getAge());
alert("Mary's name: " + mary.getName() + ", age==11: "+mary.getAge());
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses prototypical inheritance.

If you want to create custom classes I would recommend reading up what prototypical inheritance is about instead of trying to force c# methodology onto js (implementing class based inheritance over prototypical)

http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html

Comment: You're never going to implement class based inheritance in JS. You can only make it look class based. But in the end, super methods and properties are always going to be looked up the prototype chain.