# What are node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Regarding this question: [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

I'm a Javascript beginner.  In the referenced question...

mymodule.js code

```
var myFunc = function() { ... };
exports.myFunc = myFunc;
```

main js file

```
var m = require('./mymodule.js');
m.myFunc();
```

Is mymodule essentially a class file defining objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js allows code to be separated into different modules. This modules are just javascript files that can expose functions or objects using the `exports` object.

1. [There are more details of this convention](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS)
2. [Nice documentation of the Node.js modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

There are no Classes in JavaScript but you can use patterns to emulate that behaviour. There is a question about implementing OOP patterns in JavaScript: [what pattern to use when creating javascript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388458/what-pattern-to-use-when-creating-javascript-class)

As a beginner there are very good books for JavaScript:

1. [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)
2. [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752)

They are short and will give you a very good insight of the JavaScript Language.

Comment: The two links "The Good Parts", "Patterns" are not found.

Comment: URI behind the Link is `http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596806752` I can not even open any connection to rads.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

> Is mymodule essentially a class file defining objects?

and functions, although in Javascript functions *are* objects, so the distinction may be moot.

Importantly, each module has its own scope, so any `var` declared therein will not be visible outside of the module.

The rest of your question about users and lists doesn't make sense as written.  Javascript OO programming is a complete topic in its own right, and the module system doesn't really change that.  Modules are *just* a way of wrapping code libraries.