# What are the modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Regarding this question: What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it? I'm a Javascript beginner. In the referenced question...

Comment: [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311334) - what about this question?

Comment: [NodeJS Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) contain all the information you need.

Comment: Also, what about this question: [What are node.js modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11487493) yours post here is a copy of the beginning part of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider modules to be the same as JavaScript libraries.

A set of functions you want to include in your application.

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp